# Regex to split tags from non-tag string

Tags: python, regex, xml

**How to split tags from non-tag string?**

Assume that:

- Any substring between `<...>` are tags
- A single `<` with other strings without `>` are non-tags

Given:

```
<div><div><div><div><div>acsc<div>abcd</div>
>acsc<div>abcd</div>
<div>abcd </div>
<div>abcd 
abcd efg </div>
abcd efg</div>
<div> zxc>aa <asc>asca asca> acsa<>asca acasc>
as>aca>asc a<aca< <aca>asca>
<asvajvaolqwd> avaskmlv> avasv><avsva>asca
```

Expected output:

```
[['<div>', '<div>', '<div>', '<div>', '<div>', 'acsc', '<div>', 'abcd', '</div>'], 
['>acsc', '<div>', 'abcd', '</div>'], 
['<div>', 'abcd', '</div>'], 
['<div>', 'abcd'], 
['abcd', 'efg', '</div>'], 
['abcd', 'efg', '</div>'], 
['<div>', 'zxc>aa', '<asc>', 'asca', 'asca>', 'acsa', '<>', 'asca', 'acasc>'], 
['as>aca>asc', 'a<aca<', '<aca>', 'asca>'], 
['<asvajvaolqwd>', 'avaskmlv>', 'avasv>', '<avsva>', 'asca']]
```

## Attempt 1

I've tried this regex to try to catch `<...> ... </...>` groups but it's catching only the one instance of the tags:

```
(<.*(?<=>))(.*)((?=<\/)[^>]*>)
```

E.g.

```
>>> import re

>>> x = """
... <div> <div> <div> <div> <div> acsc <div> abcd </div>
... >acsc <div> abcd </div>
... <div> abcd </div>
... <div> abcd 
... abcd efg </div>
... abcd efg </div>
... <div> zxc>aa <asc> asca asca> acsa <> asca acasc>
... as>aca>asc a<aca< <aca> asca>
... <asvajvaolqwd> avaskmlv> avasv> <avsva> asca"""


>>> [re.findall(r"(<.*(?<=>))(.*)((?=<\/)[^>]*>)", line) for line in x.split('\n')]
[[], [('<div> <div> <div> <div> <div> acsc <div>', ' abcd ', '</div>')], [('<div>', ' abcd ', '</div>')], [('<div>', ' abcd ', '</div>')], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

## Attempt 2

Then I tried

```
((?=<)[^>]*>)
```

I could find out all the possible tag locations:

```
>>> [re.findall(r"((?=<)[^>]*>)", line) for line in x.split('\n')]
[[], ['<div>', '<div>', '<div>', '<div>', '<div>', '<div>', '</div>'], ['<div>', '</div>'], ['<div>', '</div>'], ['<div>'], ['</div>'], ['</div>'], ['<div>', '<asc>', '<>'], ['<aca< <aca>'], ['<asvajvaolqwd>', '<avsva>']]
```

Still not the expected output, moreover for the `<aca< <aca>`, it was greedy and caught it as one instead of `['<aca<', '<aca>']`. **How do make the findall non-greedy?**

Comment: This has been asked and answered ad nauseum.   [Don't parse XML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/290085)  Use a real XML parser.